# How can I crash an iOS app when a function designed for symbolic breakpoints is triggered?

Tags: ios, breakpoints, dyld

I want to make sure that certain functions designed to be caught by symbolic breakpoints, such as `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints`, are not triggered during UI testing. However, I don't want to have the phone hooked up to the debugger and catching breakpoints. Instead, I want to crash the app somehow when these functions are run. How can I do this? Would dyld interposing help?

Answer (score -1):

Put a @try @catch around your call to UIApplicationMain.
In the @catch block call:

```
kill( getpid(), SIGTRAP); //or SIGKILL
```

Comment: The issue is that these functions generally don't throw exceptions